# SPIN output results

Tags: spin, promela

I have written Promela code to verify the Needham-Schroeder protocol using SPIN.
After running a random simulation of the code I receive this output:

```
  0:    proc  - (:root:) creates proc  0 (:init:)
Starting PIni with pid 1
  1:    proc  0 (:init:) creates proc  1 (PIni)
0 :init ini run PIni(A,I,N 
Starting PRes with pid 2
  3:    proc  0 (:init:) creates proc  2 (PRes)
0 :init ini run PRes(B,Nb) 
Starting PI with pid 3
  4:    proc  0 (:init:) creates proc  3 (PI)
0 :init ini run PI()       
1 PIni  62  else           
1 PIni  63  1              
1 PIni  64  ca!self,nonce, 
3 PI    128 ca?,x1,x2,x3   
1 PIni  64  values: 1!A,Na 
3 PI    128 values: 1?0,Na 
Process Statement          PI(3):kNa  PI(3):x1   PI(3):x2   PI(3):x3   
3 PI    135 x3 = 0         1          0          0          I          
3 PI    101 ca!B,gD,A,B    1          0          0          0          
2 PRes  79  ca?eval(self), 1          0          0          0          
3 PI    101 values: 1!B,gD 1          0          0          0          
2 PRes  79  values: 1?B,gD 1          0          0          0          
Process Statement          PI(3):kNa  PI(3):x1   PI(3):x2   PI(3):x3   PRes(2):g2 PRes(2):g3 
2 PRes  80  g3==A)&&(self= 1          0          0          0          gD         A          
2 PRes  80  ResRunningAB = 1          0          0          0          gD         A          
Process Statement          PI(3):kNa  PI(3):x1   PI(3):x2   PI(3):x3   PRes(2):g2 PRes(2):g3 ResRunning 
2 PRes  82  ca!self,g2,non 1          0          0          0          gD         A          1          
3 PI    128 ca?,x1,x2,x3   1          0          0          0          gD         A          1          
2 PRes  82  values: 1!B,gD 1          0          0          0          gD         A          1          
3 PI    128 values: 1?0,gD 1          0          0          0          gD         A          1          
3 PI    135 x3 = 0         1          0          0          A          gD         A          1          
3 PI    113 ca!( (kNa) ->  1          0          0          0          gD         A          1          
1 PIni  68  ca?eval(self), 1          0          0          0          gD         A          1          
3 PI    113 values: 1!A,Na 1          0          0          0          gD         A          1          
1 PIni  68  values: 1?A,Na 1          0          0          0          gD         A          1          
Process Statement          PI(3):kNa  PI(3):x1   PI(3):x2   PI(3):x3   PIni(1):g1 PRes(2):g2 PRes(2):g3 ResRunning 
1 PIni  69  else           1          0          0          0          Na         gD         A          1          
1 PIni  69  1              1          0          0          0          Na         gD         A          1          
1 PIni  71  cb!self,g1,par 1          0          0          0          Na         gD         A          1          
3 PI    139 cb?,x1,x2      1          0          0          0          Na         gD         A          1          
1 PIni  71  values: 2!A,Na 1          0          0          0          Na         gD         A          1          
3 PI    139 values: 2?0,Na 1          0          0          0          Na         gD         A          1          
3 PI    145 x2 = 0         1          0          I          0          Na         gD         A          1          
timeout
#processes: 4
 34:    proc  3 (PI) needhamNew.pml:100 (state 81)
 34:    proc  2 (PRes) needhamNew.pml:86 (state 10)
 34:    proc  1 (PIni) needhamNew.pml:73 (state 18)
 34:    proc  0 (:init:) needhamNew.pml:58 (state 8)
4 processes created
```

I can see that the processes that are created which are for the Initiator, Responder and Intruder. I'm finding it difficult to see exactly how this proves that the Needham-Schroeder protocol can be broken even though I understand the theory behind it.

Can anyone make sense of this output and maybe direct me to where I should be looking?
*If you would like to view my Promela code please let me know!*
Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: My answer is not worthy of even an up-vote?  Or better a 'check mark' as a correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Near the end of the output you see `timeout` - this means that no further progress can be made which usually indicates a deadlock of some sort.  In the process list (at the end) you see the line numbers and none of them are marked as a valid `end` state.  Therefore either you have a true deadlock or your model is wrong because it fails to identify its valid end state(s).

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback! What do you suggest I do? I can't figure out whether the code I've written has an error or whether it is supposed to give me this output. It doesn't seem to show any sign of an intruder attack on the protocol. What is the next step I can take?

Comment: First, make sure you mark the valid end state(s) in each proctype.  See SPIN documentation on a) the meaning of end states and b) how to mark them (with a label that starts with end<AnythingElse>:)  Essentially if the protocol under test has no errors all procs should repeatedly pass through valid end states (or reach the end of a proctype, which is implicitly a valid end state).

Comment: Second, having marked the end states, if a timeout occurs you need to analyze, essentially by hand, what caused the deadlock.  This means tracing through the output and understanding every step taken by every process.  The print-out is showing the steps taken.

Comment: Third, you've run SPIN in 'simulation' mode.  An alternative is to run SPIN in 'verification' mode; when an error occurs, you rerun SPIN with a smaller depth to find the smallest possible number of steps to a deadlock.  See the '-I' and '-i' flags (I think, memory fades); there is also a compilation flag needed.